# Stress Performance testing on a simple java application

Tags: automated-testing, java, performance

I have a simple java application that runs on my computer. It's not connected to the internet, but it is connected to a MySQL database on my localhost.

All it does is read and write to and from my database. It generates a few random numbers, takes information from one class and passes it over to the other class and such. It's very simple.

My question is, how do I perform Performance testing on it? There are some tools available but I haven't found one suitable for my application.

I'm not even sure I can perform this kind of testing on it ...

Is it possible to do such testing on such a simple java application? If yes, which tool should I use (if any?)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should split your testing into 2 phases

1. Application profiling using profiling tools, either [open source](https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source) or paid like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)
2. Standalone database load testing. You can use any load testing tool which supports [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) protocol, i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for details.

Comment: +1 for Jmeter its a broadly used tool that should give insight to the situation described as well.

Answer (score 0):

For applications similar to this in the past what I would do is custom build a framework that executes the code in rapid succession. This can be done by using your current integration tests (if any) and setting them up to execute repeatedly over x amount of hours or x times.

I always built out custom frameworks, multi-threaded, wrapped in a monitor and then allowed the execution to run. I also built out a basic Swing based UI which allowed me to adjust the settings (IE threads, execution time) and monitor the results.

You will also want to create a wrapper which stores data like the amount of consecutive threads, the average response time, the high-low response times and the total amount of requests sent and have it displayed and/or logged.